# How to get user's data programatically, via facebook authentication?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

I am able to manually get the user's data, but not programatically.

Using the server side code, as it is, from - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

```
 <?php 

 $app_id = "MY_APP_ID";
 $app_secret = "MY_APP_SECRET";
 $my_url = "ADDRESS_OF_CURRENT_PAGE";

 session_start();
 $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 if(empty($code)) {
   $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
   $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
     . $_SESSION['state'];

   echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
 }

 if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
   $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

   $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
   $params = null;
   parse_str($response, $params);

   $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
     . $params['access_token'];

   $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
   echo("Hello " . $user->name);
 }
 else {
   echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
 }

 ?>
```

The output is only Hello, the user name does not show up!

I think the problem is with the file_get_contents(), as echo-ing $response has no output, where as $token_url has the appropriate value.

```
   $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
```

- PHP version = 5.2.9
- Error reporting is off, but including this in the code - error_reporting(E_ALL); gives no output.

**UPDATE** - So, I tried this after 6 months, and it worked. The only thing that has changed since then is my hosting. I was using HostBig before. **Lesson** - Don't depend on $1/month hosting services, they can't be trusted.

Comment: Hrm, have you tried it without the "@"?  That's suppressing errors.

Comment: One problem that I've had with file_get_contents in the past is that it doesn't give you the actual webserver response data when the response headers contain an error.  Whereas, browsers generally display the response.  It just doesn't make debugging any easier.

Comment: @finity I have tried without the '@'. In fact, I have tried numerous permutations/combinations of this code, over a time span of several hours! Nothing works. Can I avoid the file_get_contents function, and use something else instead?

Comment: Yup, you can use curl - [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).  I wrote a Facebook app a few months ago and had a heck of a time trying to debug it.  At one point Facebook just stopped responding to my queries, and I found out a few days later it was a bug that hit maybe 100 devs.  Very frustrating.  You're using a different authentication scheme than I did - mine ran as a canvas app, so Facebook sent me the access_token each time the user viewed my page.  `file_get_contents` worked well for me, but maybe curl can give you more useful debugging info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried this after 6 months, and it worked. The only thing that has changed since then is my hosting. I was using HostBig before.

There was probably something wrong with HostBig's PHP configuration, which disabled the file_get_contents().

UPDATE - I talked to the HostBig guys, and they told me that they have disabled allow_url_fopen, for reasons of safety, and suggested cURL as the safer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this code from localhost? If yes, then it wont work. While registering your app on facebook, you must have entered your app's website. Upload the script on server, edit your app_id, secret and the url of script. Then try executing it.

If it doesn't work even then, then try echoing your `$dialog_url` and `$token_url`. First manually copy paste your `$dialog_url` in browser and see what error it gives. If it asks for authentication, authenticate your app. It will get you back to the page. Then try running your `$token_url` in browser. It will give you the exact response what the server is providing you with.

Comment: I am running on the server. And like I said, when I echo $token_url, and paste it in the address bar, I get the token, and expiry time. I have also used that token to get info from the graph in the same fashion.